# c programming while((c = getchar()) != EOF)

Tags: c

I'm learning a c programming myself. But I met some questions hard to understand to me. The problem is:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
```

The reason why I'm confused is that I know that `getchar()` can accommodate only one character, so if I entered `"wow"` how does this loop print `"wow"`? I can't make sense the flow chart of the loop.

For example, (following is the flow chart I'm thinking)

input:wow

1. assigns `'w'` to `c`
2. prints the `'w'`

Then where is the rest of the word `"ow"`? Also, how does this loop print rest of the word `"ow"`?

Comment: That's what the loop is for. It reads characters one by one until [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns `EOF`. Perhaps you might need to take a step back and refresh your knowledge of basic C constructs and statements?

Comment: `while` is a loop, which means it executes the code repeatedly.

Comment: then, while printing the word "w", where is the rest of the word "ow" stored? I think that getchar() can only store one character.

Comment: "ow" stays in the `stdin` file stream. The next time you `getchar` it takes one more character, until it reaches EOF.

Comment: Oh, I got it. I appreciate all of you to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a loop, so it executes repeatedly until the `while` condition fails.

1. Execute `c = getchar()`. This reads the character `'w'` into `c`.
2. Test whether this is not equal to `EOF`. This is true, so we continue with the body of the loop.
3. Print `c`, which prints `'w'`.
4. Go back to the beginning of the loop.
5. Execute `c = getchar()`. This reads the character `'o'` into `c`.
6. Test whether this is not equal to `EOF`. This is true, so we continue with the body of the loop.
7. Print `c`, which prints `'o'`.
8. Go back to the beginning of the loop.
9. Execute `c = getchar()`. This reads the character `'w'` into `c`.
10. Test whether this is not equal to `EOF`. This is true, so we continue with the body of the loop.
11. Print `c`, which prints `'w'`.
12. Go back to the beginning of the loop.
13. Execute `c = getchar()`. This reads `EOF` into `c`.
14. Test whether this is not equal to `EOF`. This is false, so the loop ends.

So we printed `w` in step 3, `o` in step 7, and the second `w` in step 11.

What you were missing is that it calls `getchar()` each time through the loop, which reads the next character.